# Is there a Python way to select from a data set of URL links the ones that only have 200 status code?

Tags: python

I have scraped a web page to collect all the URL links on the page. Finally got it working but looked back at the instructions and I need to be sure that the URL's are actually links meaning Status code 200.  So is there a way to filter for only the 200's.  I am new to Python.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try the `requests` module?

From https://2.python-requests.org//en/v2.9.1/

```
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass')) 

>>> r.status_code
200
```

You should be able to collect all links that report a http 200 status code in a list if you need to. Then do whatever you want with them. Just an idea.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  The only thing about this code is that it looks it  requires you to hard code and enter an actual URL.  What I am doing is scraping URL links from a web page to write to a CSV file.  What I need is to be able to only accept the ones that are valid URL with a return code of 200.  I am completely new to Python.  My background is in SAS.

Comment: The answer below has an example of a function that takes a list as an argument. Simply create a list of urls and pass it to the 'valid' function. It is a good working example. 'valid(listofurls)' should give you a list of only urls with status 200. Should be excepted as the answer.

Comment: ahhhhh by God this looks good. Thank you will go plug in now.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got requests installed:

```
def valid(urls): # urls is a list of links
    import requests
    returnValue = [u for u in urls if requests.get(u).status_code == 200]
    return returnValue
```

If not, you could use urllib, but it's different:

```
def valid_without_requests(urls): # urls is a list of links
    import urllib
    returnValue = [r for r in urls if urllib.urlopen(r).getcode() == 200]
    return returnValue
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Perhaps you would be kind enough to click the green check?